# Why are some javascript files named with _ in front of the name?

Tags: reactjs

I'm going through a react application tutorial and there are files that start with _app.js what is the purpose of naming the files like that?

Comment: How would that answer his question @Jagrati? He specifically asked for '_' in filenames, not in names of properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

It has no specific purpose. Generally in scss we prefix some files with "*" to indicate they are partial templates. In JavaScript we don't need that. It could be just a convention they are following inspired from different coding language. As far as javascript is concerned, filenames need not be prefixed with "*"